# Реестр и Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Доброго времени суток. Изучаю С++ не давно, потому есть кучка вопросов касающихся работы с реестром.

Вот предположим есть на форме 2 кнопки, приведите пожалуйста такой код,чтобы при нажатии на одну кнопку создался раздел в реестре и параметр со значением, а при нажатии на другую информация оттуда бы считалась и присвоилась, например, к лабелу. Зарание спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Using the Registry in a C++ Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838625.aspx)
- [Чтение данных из реестра Windows (C++/CLI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/df4afx57(v=vs.100).aspx)

Например, чтение из реестра с помощью Windows API

```
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, &key, &disposition) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    type = REG_DWORD;
    size = sizeof(DWORD);
    RegQueryValueEx(key, name, NULL, &type, (PBYTE)&data, &size);

    RegCloseKey(key);
}
```

Код на чтение-запись нужно поместить в обработчик нажатия кнопки.

Comment: Выдает список ошибок, ругается на то, что RegCreateKeyEx, type, DWORD, NULL и т.п. не объявлены

Comment: `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: Спасибо, ошибок стало меньше, но все еще ругается на: data, name, key, path, type, disposition, size.